# is a Joule of energy relatively different in a different gravitational potential due to time dilation?

Tags: energy, time-dilation

A joule of energy is a function of kg x m^2 x s^-2    so it is related to time.  Would this mean that if I am looking from earth to a much larger planet with greater gravitational time dilation, that I would see a Joule of energy as relatively larger?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this one has to develop the definition of terms very carefully. How shall we define "one joule"? One definition could be:

1 joule = the rest mass energy of $6.65 \times 10^9$ hydrogen atoms

The idea of this definition is to connect an energy to a physical thing which could in principle be counted unambiguously (the number of hydrogen atoms).

Now suppose you have got that number of hydrogen atoms, sitting on the surface of a large planet, and I have got that same number of hydrogen atoms, located far from any planet or other gravitating body. So by the above definition, we have each got 1 joule. But my joule can do more than your joule! I could, for example, lower my hydrogen atoms down to the surface of your planet, dangling them on a rope, and I could use the rope to turn a generator or charge a battery or whatever as I lowered the atoms. So at the end we both have a joule at the planet's surface, but I also have some further energy.

In a Newtonian picture one would say that this further energy was there at the outset, in my atoms, contained in their gravitational potential energy. So one might argue that I had more energy all along. That's fine. But then it means we have to either accept the picture I just gave, or else modify our definition of one joule. A modified definition could be, for example:

1 joule = the rest mass energy of $6.65 \times 10^9$ hydrogen atoms located at spacetime location P (where P has to specified in some way)

In either case, no matter what definition you adopt, it turns out that comparing energies at different places in spacetime is a tricky business. The upshot is that
your initial intuition was basically correct. Amount of energy is a relative concept, which depends on spacetime location. More generally, if something in special relativity varies from one inertial frame to another, then in general relativity it will also vary from one spacetime location to another.

Here are some further examples. For a particle in free-fall, does its kinetic energy change as it falls? The answer depends: you have to say, 'kinetic energy with respect to which local inertial frame?' Also, if you convert rest-mass energy of something to electromagnetic radiation at one place, and send the electromagnetic waves to a higher-up place, and then try to use them to re-construct the thing you started with, then it won't work. There won't be enough energy in the electromagnetic radiation. This does not make the science-fiction transporter in Star Trek impossible; it means the Starship Enterprise or whatever will have to supply the required extra energy. (An efficient transporter design might allow for this by gathering and storing the required energy when the crew was beamed down to the planet surface in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Would not your formula "1 joule = the rest mass energy of 6.65×109 hydrogen atoms"  be considered as a derivative of my original time based formula, based on e=mc^2 ? That is, it only explains potential energy, rather than working energy?  So it still just takes us back to my time based formula.

Comment: A time-based definition is indeed perfectly fine and my main message is that whatever definition you start out from, it will end up with the kinds of issues I described. In a time-based definition one has to decide how one unit of time relates to one unit of energy. One could define units such that Planck's constant takes a simple value such as 1. But a clock sitting on a planet would still have to be compared with a clock somewhere else, and the normal comparison is that if they are the same kind of clock then the upper one ticks faster....

Comment: That implies that if you take same Planck's constant at both places, then the higher-up 'one joule' is larger than the lower-down 'one joule'. But in another sense they are equal, because the energy thus defined will be able to do the same amount of local things in each place, such as make hydrogen atoms or compress a spring or charge a battery or whatever.

Comment: Of course the "proper energy" would be directly related to "proper time" in terms of a local observer versus a remote observer.  The issue becomes which comes first, the chicken or the egg.

Comment: @foolishmuse yes.